# What is the "post name" equivalent to for <?php the_permalink() ?>? (in Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

Under Permalink Structure in WP, I have selected "Post Name" ... in my index I have this statement that works correctly,  but ONLY if I have "Default" selected under Permalink Structure:

```
<h1><a class= "title" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

So in theory, I need something like  but that represents the "post name" or "/%postname%/" ... I hope that makes sense.

TIA

Comment: What happens if you select 'Post Name' as permalink in settings ? Doesn't it work ?

Comment: it says, "The requested URL /wordpress/testing/ was not found on this server."  ...I am working on the localhost...

Comment: It may be some different issue other than permalink settings. Do you get 404 error on even homepage of your wordpress URL ?

Comment: no 404...it just says, "Not Found

The requested URL /wordpress/testing/ was not found on this server."

Comment: What have you specified as Blog URL in General Settings of Wordpress ?

Comment: both WP Address URL and Site Address URL are just 'http://localhost/wordpress'

Comment: Have you updated your `.htaccess` file with the code provided at the bottom of the permalink settings page?

Comment: I am trying to find the .htaccess file.  Are you referring to adding the rewrite code to the page?   Thanks

Comment: OK...so I updated the .htaccess file and the apache file. Now I go to http://localhost/wordpress/testing/ and it takes me to the WAMPSERVER home page....?